# Cannot ssh to remote host on Tunnelblick

Tags: terminal, network, ssh, vpn, dns

I'm wondering if there are any Tunnelblick users that can suggest some troubleshooting steps.

I use Tunnelblick to connect to my university VPN so I can access ssh servers. It usually works just fine but occasionally with no warning I'm unable to connect to the servers i.e ssh error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname XX: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

There are never any errors in the Tunnelblick log so I'm not sure what I can troubleshoot.
I can confirm that the host is still up since I can connect by tunnelling my ssh connection through the department main server which doesn't require VPN access.

Any advice would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: I am facing the same problem from time to time. I have no idea what's causing it. :-( I also tried reconnecting, without success though.

Comment: @Arvid For me there was a nameserver error, try sshing with the IP of the host